# Java Process watcher

Tags: java, process

Is it possible in java to wait to see if a process is killed and if it is to immediately restart it?

A bit more in depth of what I am trying to do:

App1(main)
Starts separate process app2 / thread that watches app1(main)
if app 2 is killed it restarts it
(Does other code)

App2
Watches main process/app1 and if it is killed it restarts it

I would appreciate any help you could provide. I looked through the java docs of the process and processbuider classes and didn't notice anything that might help me out.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to write malware..

Comment: Nah, though I could see why you would think that. Java 2 GUI from hell project. Supposed to make it as annoying as possible and this was one of my ideas.

Comment: Well, looks like `Process.WaitFor` would help you? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

Comment: Looks like it may, is there anyway to make it so (app2 in this example) knows if the main is killed?

Answer (score 0):

```
while(true){
   ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(commandList);
    try {
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        try {
              process.waitFor();
               // this is wait until process killed.
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```